# Converting a column with address and coordinates to string with .astype(str) drops the coordinates

Tags: python, regex, string, geocoding, geopy

I'm using the geopy package to search address for their coordinates, with the column returning the matched address and coordinates

I want to just get the coordinates

Here is a test to show you how it works:

```
# Test to see if response is obtained for easy address
location = geolocator.geocode("175 5th Avenue NYC", timeout=10)
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))

>>> (40.7410861, -73.9896298241625)
```

In my code I have a CSV with cities, that are then looked up using the geopy package

```
data['geocode_result'] = [geolocator.geocode(x, timeout = 60) for x in data['ghana_city']]
```

[image]

I want to just get the coordinates from here

Using extract doesn't seem to work and just returns NaN values despite the regex being fine:

```
p = r'(?P<latitude>-?\d+\.\d+)?(?P<longitude>-?\d+\.\d+)'
data[['g_latitude', 'g_longitude']] = data['geocode_result2'].str.extract(p, expand=True)
data
```

I have a feeling that these problems are coming about due to the object that's returned from geopy in the column

**The regex is sound, as verified on Regexr.com:**

[image]

I have tried converting the column to a string, **but the coordinates are dropped?!**

```
data['geocode_result2'] = (data['geocode_result2']).astype(str)
data
```

[image]

Can anyone help here? thanks a lot

---

Dummy data:

The column I want to extract the coordinates from is geocode_result2 or geocode_result

```
     geocode_result2
1    (Agona Swedru, Central Region, Ghana, (5.534454, -0.700763))
2    (Madina, Adenta, Greater Accra Region, PMB 107 MD, Ghana, (5.6864962, -0.1677052))
3    (Ashaiman, Greater Accra Region, TM3 8AA, Ghana, (5.77329565, -0.110766330148484))
```

---

Final code to get coordinates:

```
data['geocode_result'] = [geolocator.geocode(x, timeout = 60) for x in data['ghana_city']]
x = data['geocode_result']
data.dropna(subset=['geocode_result'], inplace=True)
data['g_latitude'] = data['geocode_result'].apply(lambda loc: loc.latitude)
data['g_longitude'] = data['geocode_result'].apply(lambda loc: loc.longitude)
data
```

Comment: Try `p = r'(?P<latitude>-?\d+\.\d+),\s*(?P<longitude>-?\d+\.\d+)'` There are commas and whitespace chars between the 2 values, right?

Comment: Thanks for your help, i've actually tried this before. And also tried making the regex very simple. I have a feeling that it's the .str that isn't working correctly though

Comment: When I do dtype on the column it returns 'object' which isn't suspicious, but I can't seem to convert the damn thing without the coordinates being dropped which is what I believe I need to do for the extract to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`geolocator.geocode` returns `Location` object rather than a string (though its string representation actually contains lat/long which you were trying to parse), so lat/long can be retrieved by accessing `location.latitude`/ `location.longitude` attributes respectively.

```
# Make geocoding requests
data['geocode_result'] = [geolocator.geocode(x, timeout = 60) for x in data['ghana_city']]
# Extract lat/long to separate columns
data['g_latitude'] = data['geocode_result'].apply(lambda loc: loc.latitude)
data['g_longitude'] = data['geocode_result'].apply(lambda loc: loc.longitude)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJxgE.png)

(I'm unable to comment due to reputation lack, so I'm answering the coordinates drop confusion here).

`str(location)` returns a textual address (without coordinates), but `repr(location)` returns a string in the following format (which includes the coordinates):

```
Location(%(address)s, (%(latitude)s, %(longitude)s, %(altitude)s))
```

What you see when you print `data` uses `repr` (pandas seems to drop the leading `Location` type for brevity), so you can see the coordinates. But when the column is converted to `str`, it uses `str` representation, which doesn't include the coordinates. That's the whole magic here.

Comment: thanks for answering, I get an error using your code "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'latitude'"

Comment: You have to drop the rows having None first. Try `data = data.dropna(axis=0)`

Comment: That's it - Thanks Kostya for everything

Answer (score 1):

Your can try by using `.apply` and `.str`

**Ex:**

```
def getLatLog(d):
    try:
        return re.findall(r"\d+\.\d+", d)
    except:
        return [None, None]

df['g_latitude'], df['g_longitude'] = df["geocode_result2"].apply(lambda x: getLatLog(x)).str
print(df["g_latitude"])
print(df["g_longitude"])
```

**Output:**

```
0      5.534454
1     5.6864962
2    5.77329565
Name: g_latitude, dtype: object
0             0.700763
1            0.1677052
2    0.110766330148484
Name: g_longitude, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks Rakesh, this is actually throwing the error "not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)" - which doesn't seem to make sense as at least the first couple of rows in the dataframe contain floats

Comment: Can you post your data['geocode_result2'] so that I can test. It works with my dummy data

Comment: Cheers, i've edited my answer to include 3 rows from geocode_result2

Comment: Interesting when I remove the .str from 'data['g_latitude'], data['g_longitude'] = data["geocode_result2"].apply(lambda x: getLatLog(x)).str' I have ;too MANY values to unpack

Comment: Do you think it could be that the column I have is taken from the response from the geopy package opposed to me entering strings in the columns, which is causing the issues?

Comment: Interestingly, when trying to write to CSV, the coordinates are dropped from geocode_result as well